# Segmenting individual blobs connected by boundaries

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let's say I have the following image.
[image]

I want to consider these two blobs as two separate blobs; however, finding connected components labels them as a single component because they are touching.

I tried `img = bwmorph(img, 'branchpoints');` and that does segment and erode these two blobs but that also erases blobs other blobs. For instance, in the following image, the upper left structure has been erased, but that structure should not be erased and moreover, I would like to segment that structure as two blobs that can be evidently seen.

[image]
[image]

The unfilled blob on the left has disappeared. How to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an idea, use `imfill` to fill holes in your blobs:

```
bw=imfill(im,'holes');
```

then do `bw-im` and get this:

[image]

you can take it from there...

Comment: What an interesting idea! Filling in the object and then just removing the borders should disconnect them. Fantastic, thank you so much!